# "Entity Object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" Using EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

```
       public bool UpdateDetails(Block _updateblock)
       {
             using (var context = new DbContext())
            {
                context.blocks.Attach(_updateblock);   
                context.Entry(_updateblock).State=System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
               return true;
               }

        }

        public void getValues()
        {
            using (var context = new DbContext())
            {
                var block = (Block)context.Blocks.Where(x => x.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();

                var sh = (Stakeholder)context.Stakeholders.Where(s =>s.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
                sh.Ownership = "100";
                block.StakeHolders.Add(sh);
               UpdateDetails(block);

            }
        }
```

//While calling "UpdateDetails(block)" method i am getting error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker." How i can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you keep a reference to _updateBlock somewhere in an upper layer (maybe your presentation layer) of your application. next time when you want to update that entity, it is very possible to receive an error.

Solutions:

1) Try to check first if entity is present already on your context.
Use

```
context.ChangeTracker.Entries< Block >().ToList ().Contains (_updateBlock);
```

But beware that this is unfortunatelly O (N). So if you have a list of N elements to update, the overall execution time will be of N^2 order.

2) Detach entity (after calling saveChanges). I would do this using try / finally to make sure that it will be detached no matter what.

3) Avoid passing EF entities to upper layers. Instead, build them every time from so called "presentation entities". Use presentation entities for storing and presenting data on your interface.

4) Switch to POCO objects. This will prevent an entity knowing what context has a reference to it.